# Concatenating url pages as a single Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to download historic weather data for a given Location.
I have altered an example given at [flowingdata](http://flowingdata.com/2007/07/09/grabbing-weather-underground-data-with-beautifulsoup/) but I've stuck in the last step - how to concate multiple `Data Frames`

**MWE:**

```py
import pandas as pd

frames = pd.DataFrame(columns=['TimeEET', 'TemperatureC', 'Dew PointC', 'Humidity','Sea Level PressurehPa', 
       'VisibilityKm', 'Wind Direction', 'Wind SpeedKm/h','Gust SpeedKm/h','Precipitationmm', 
       'Events','Conditions', 'WindDirDegrees', 'DateUTC<br />'])

# Iterate through year, month, and day
for y in range(2006, 2007):
    for m in range(1, 13):
       for d in range(1, 32):

# Check if leap year
        if y%400 == 0:
            leap = True
        elif y%100 == 0:
            leap = False
        elif y%4 == 0:
            leap = True
        else:
            leap = False

#Check if already gone through month
        if (m == 2 and leap and d > 29):
            continue
        elif (m == 2 and d > 28):
            continue
        elif (m in [4, 6, 9, 10] and d > 30):
            continue

 # Open wunderground.com url
        url = "http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/EFHK/"+str(y)+ "/" + str(m) + "/" + str(d) + "/DailyHistory.html?req_city=Vantaa&req_state=&req_statename=Finlandia&reqdb.zip=00000&reqdb.magic=4&reqdb.wmo=02974&format=1"
        df=pd.read_csv(url, sep=',',skiprows=2)
        frames=pd.concat(df)
```

This gives an error:

```
 first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"
```

The desired output would be to have one Data Frame with all days,month and years.

Comment: you want to declare a list of dfs outside your loop and then concat at the end so `df_list=[]` and then after `df=pd.read_csv(url, sep=',',skiprows=2)` do `df_list.append(df)` and then outside the loop `frames = pd.concat(df_list)`

Comment: What are you doing with all the dates?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham you mean with column DateUTC ? If yes, next step would be to clean <br /> from each cell, then set this column as an index.

Comment: I mean there are a lot easier and more reliable ways to get date ranges

Comment: Ok, now I get it. You were asking about checking the leap year and months.  The dates ranges looks like this because I need to changes the url address according to day and month. I guess they are more reliable ways to do it but on first sight it works and it is understandably for me. @PadraicCunningham can you suggest something which will work better ?

Comment: do you want all dates between those two ranges or what is the exact criteria?

Comment: Yes, I need all days, months, and years in given range.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81435/discussion-between-michal-and-padraic-cunningham).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare a list outside your loop and append to this then outside the loop you want to concatenate all the dfs into a single df:

```
import pandas as pd

frames = pd.DataFrame(columns=['TimeEET', 'TemperatureC', 'Dew PointC', 'Humidity','Sea Level PressurehPa', 
       'VisibilityKm', 'Wind Direction', 'Wind SpeedKm/h','Gust SpeedKm/h','Precipitationmm', 
       'Events','Conditions', 'WindDirDegrees', 'DateUTC<br />'])

# Iterate through year, month, and day
df_list = []
for y in range(2006, 2007):
    for m in range(1, 13):
       for d in range(1, 32):

# Check if leap year
        if y%400 == 0:
            leap = True
        elif y%100 == 0:
            leap = False
        elif y%4 == 0:
            leap = True
        else:
            leap = False

#Check if already gone through month
        if (m == 2 and leap and d > 29):
            continue
        elif (m == 2 and d > 28):
            continue
        elif (m in [4, 6, 9, 10] and d > 30):
            continue

 # Open wunderground.com url
        url = "http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/EFHK/"+str(y)+ "/" + str(m) + "/" + str(d) + "/DailyHistory.html?req_city=Vantaa&req_state=&req_statename=Finlandia&reqdb.zip=00000&reqdb.magic=4&reqdb.wmo=02974&format=1"
        df=pd.read_csv(url, sep=',',skiprows=2)
        df_list.append(df)
frames=pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: I must say that for me it is confusing to use append and concat a the same time. I always thought that `append` adds new Data Frame as a new columns, and `concat` rows or columns if set `axis=1`.... Anyway thank you !